# Raspberry pi and windows 10 laptop bridge

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, bridge

I am using raspberry pi as my development server. It is connected to the router so that my pi and windows 10 laptop are in the same network.

Now, I have problem when bring my pi and laptop to other places. When I need internet connection on my pi, I cannot do it. Although I can get internet on my laptop through wifi.

I read that windows 10 network bridge can solve this. I tried to bridge my wireless and my local area network. It seemed bridged successfully. But still, I cannot get internet access on my pi. On my pi, I used raspbian os, I did not change anything. It has static ip, gateway to 192.168.1.1, dns-server also to 192.168.1.1. FYI, the other place is a home network with default setting, modem/router ip is 192.168.1.1.

Someone can help?

Comment: what operating system on your pi?  windows 10?

Comment: You proabably want to use DHCP for network configuration.

Comment: I am using raspbian on my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

On your Windows computer you can share your WiFi connection through the Ethernet port. It is in the network properties in the control panel. Set  Pi to dynamic IP.

To connect to the pi,  use raspberrypi.local instead of a up address (you windows computer needs bonjour for this to work,  downloading iTunes is the easiest way to add it,  and it still works if you uninstall iTunes)

Comment: What is the different between network bridge to share?

Comment: Not 100% sure. We could be talking about the same thing. I'm just starting what works.  I will add some photos if you need it.